# Who are the female dancers in Eiffel 65's "Dj With The Fire" music video?

Tags: music-video, names, unknown-performer

Eiffel 65's music video for "Dj With The Fire," which is on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLRn-UNuO80), is a pretty cool one in my opinion. But something I have started to wonder is who the female dancers from the video are, who constantly flash in and out, grooving sometimes in the background and sometimes as the center of attention.

There appears to be three (symbolic for each member of Eiffel 65 perhaps) distinct dancers as far as I can tell. Here are pictures of all of them (taken from the video of course). I have tried to show as much facial area as possible.

JUST IN CASE: These images are **NOT** meant to show, hint at, or indulge in anything sexual or otherwise; they are merely for identifications purposes **only.**

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Is there any documention, official sources, etc. that identifies who any of them are? It is a curiosity to me, how these three women were in the official video for one of the most popular Italian bands of all time and yet remain nearly unknown.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about identifying dancers and not music related

Comment: Related meta-discussion: https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395/can-i-ask-this-question-in-music-fans-se